# WSO2 5.11 Console trying to reach localhost instead server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 IS 5.11 installed on a server under https://server1.wso2.com.
When Im trying to reach new console app Im getting redirected to:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

and then to authorize endpoint:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CONSOLE&scope=SYSTEM%20openid&redirect_uri=https://server1.wso2.com/console/login&response_mode=query&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=sa3xryaGoX1IoyxZJfoIrE3tAJPUjep30j6izcDtOtc
```

Why Im getting redirected to localhost:9443? I checked my configuration and there is no localhost in resident IdP.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to the server configurations set on WSO2IS, to change that go to `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf` directory and open `deployment.toml` configuration file and change the

```
[server]
hostname = "https://server1.wso2.com"
```

Also, you can check load balancer configurations/ port mapping and opening ports from the server configurations from the server that you use.